# Rejected edit with a typo fixed

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, moderation

I've answered a question and made a typo in the response (missing semicolon). Someone tried to fix that, however the edit was rejected by moderators in [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12573039).

Is that the correct behaviour on Stack Overflow? In my opinion, instead of rejecting, it would be better for the reviewers to improve the edit instead by removing the `// added missing semicolon` comment from suggested edit and leaving the semicolon.

Comment: **This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.** SO already has an answer to your question in review message. In my opinion, you should not edit the code let the OP do it, you just comment the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obvious typos in code can and should be fixed by editing. The correct way would be re-edit (*reject & edit* or *improve edit*) and remove that `//` comment. At least that's what I would do.

On the other hand, one should not really make such edits in the first place if you have to add some dummy text to submit the edit. A comment would be enough.

<sub>On a side note: The edit was rejected by normal users, not moderators.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

That, while correct, is a trivial edit. A comment to you as notification of the fault would have sufficed. A 2000+ rep user could have done it as well. Some type of rejection seems justified in this case.

Comments in code are for code clarification. Not notices about edits on content. I suspect the user did that to get past the character limit which is poor justification.

Answer (score 3):

I'd personally go with reject and edit.  The extra noise in the post itself with a rather distracting comment definitely deserves to be rejected.  Improving the post implicitly approves the inappropriate work-around for the character limit.  That is no good.  And since the edit is really so small, I would just reject and edit to send the message that this kind of edit that adds noise is unacceptable.